# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) please help me with this error

Tags: python

```
T = int(input())
for tc in range(T):
    # Read integers a and b.
    (a, b) = map(int, input().split(' '))
    
    ans = a + b
    print(ans)
```

Comment: what is your input? If you enter `1<enter>2 3<enter>` you don't get an error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
T = int(input("Enter number of times for loop to run as per your input"))
for tc in range(T):
    (a, b) = map(int, input().split(' '))
    ans = a + b
    print(ans)
```

When you first run, it will ask for the number of testcases you want. After that you have to provide your numbers with a space between two numbers as you mention in a `split(' ')`. If you mention `'-'` in `split` you have to provide a `'-'` between two input numbers.
Also, you can add the `strip()` function in front of `split()` to avoid errors due to whitespace in the input.